# Should variable bound in SELECT clause be accessible in ORDER BY?

Tags: scope, sparql, specifications

Should this be valid SPARQL?

```
SELECT ("text" AS ?aString)
WHERE {}
ORDER BY ?aString
```

I have tried two different engines. One returns "text" for ?aString, the other errors, saying that ?aString is not defined in the ORDER BY. Does the SPARQL spec cover this case? Or is this just an implementation detail, where it happens to work in some engines, but is not strictly portable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be portable.  What engine says it's not legal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html) says it's legal.  This is actually a pretty important case, since we want to be able to do things like:

```sql
select ?min ?max ((?max - ?min) as ?range) {
  #-- ...
}
order by ?range
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that validator. Couldn't your query also be expressed as: `SELECT ?min ?max ?range WHERE { BIND((?max - ?min) AS ?range) #-- ... } ORDER BY ?range` ? I too was thinking that there must be cases where this is necessary, but I couldn't come up with any

Comment: you can't use bind if the ?min and ?max were aggregates, though.  E.g., `select (min(?x) as ?min) (max(?x) as ?max) (?max - ?min as ?range) { ... } order by ?range`.

Answer (score 2):

A SPARQL query (actually, one level, i.e. SELECT, of query) splits in pattern pattern and operations on the results of the pattern. Those operations are called modifiers.

They happen in the sequence:

```
order - project - distinct - reduces - offset - limit
```

`SELECT` is complicated - it isn't just one modifier and it isn't just a projection. The `AS` in the example has two aspects and it becomes like `BIND` done as the final pattern stage and also includes the variable in the project.

This query has exactly the same SPARQL algebra form as the one in the query.

```
SELECT ?aString
WHERE {
    ...
    BIND ("text" AS ?aString)
}
ORDER BY ?aString
```

or in the algebra:

```
(project (?aString)
  (order (?aString)
    (extend ((?aString "text"))
      ...)))
```

which is evaluated inside-out.

`?aString` is defined before order happens and `ORDER BY` can sort using it.